# Primary key change from Int to bigint?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

When your int primary key runs out can you change its data type to bigint? (its not going to be a problem?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from the impact to the database itself your code will likely get impacted too. The int field of parameter will have to be changed from int to long, any conversions you're doing from say string to int will have to be changed as well.

Nothing wrong, however, if you feel that there is a very strong possibility, I suggest you make it a bigint to start with.

Comment: what happens if you dont change it to int? overflows?

Comment: Do you mean don't change it to long? considering that the fields in question will most likely be auto generated and you'll then try and assign these values to a property of a class whose data type is int, there is no implicit conversion from long to int in C#. So your code won't compile. I'm not sure I really understand your question honestly. What happens if you don't change what to an int? Or maybe it just 3 am and I'm dead beat.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, nothing will happen. You are just increasing the set byte size. So all id's will stay as they were and allowing you more positions after the change.

Answer (score 0):

Doing so will cause the entire primary key to be rewritten, so that will most likely take a significant amount of time. However apart from that there is no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

This depends how many, how much and which dependencies do you have and not only in database but also in client apps.